# Proper struc array declaration

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to translate matlab/gnu octave code into gfortran language code.

I have done declaration of struc to form an array as it is written in matlab.  However the compiler will not process the SIZE command due to that array issue that I do not understand.  Below is the octave code I am trying to translate

```
function test1
clc;
close all;
start= 5;
function out = function1(start)
myarray = struct(...
    'list1', {'A', 'Cc', 'B', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'}, ...
    'list2', {1, 2,  3,  4, 5, 6, 7, 8},...
    'list3', {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2});
function list1 = function2(list2)
    done = false;
    myarray    
    numel(myarray)
    ra = randi([1 numel(myarray)], 1, 1)
    myarray(ra).list2;

    list1 = myarray(ra);
    if list1.list1 == 'E'
        list1.list1 = round(randn(1,1) * 5);
    end
   end
  x = {}; 
  y = [];
  list2 = 0;    
    list1 = function2(list2);
    list2 = list2 + list1.list3;
  out = struct('x', {x}, 'y', {y});
 end
function1(5)
end
```

The output of the octave code is,

```
test1

myarray =

1x8 struct array containing the fields:

list1
list2
list3

ans =  8
ra =  1
ans =

scalar structure containing the fields:

x = {}(0x0)
y = [](0x0)
```

My gfortran code is,

```
function function1(start) result(out1)

 type myarray
 character, dimension(8)::list1=(/'A','C','B','E','F','G','H','I'/); 
 integer, dimension(8)::list2 =(/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8/); 
 integer, dimension(8)::list3 =(/3,3,3,3,3,2,2/);
  end type 

  integer :: start;
  integer :: out1;
  integer :: sd;

 contains

  function function2(list2) result(list1)

   integer, intent(in) :: list2; ! input
   integer :: list1;             ! output  
   logical :: done;  
   integer, dimension(1,1) :: ra;
   real    :: rnd1;

    done = .FALSE.


    call random_number(rnd1);
    ra = nint(rnd1*5);
    sd= size(myarray);
   ! ra = nint(rnd1*size(myarray));
       print*, "random number is ", ra;
     myarray(ra)

 end function function2

 end function function1

program test1
use iso_fortran_env
implicit none

integer                 :: start, xout;
real                    :: ra;
integer                 :: function1;

start =5;
xout=function1(5);
end program test1
```

The error message I get from build command is:

```
gfortran  -Ofast -Wall -o "test1" "test1.f90"  
test1.f90:32:16:
      myarray(ra).list2;
            1
Error: Derived type ‘myarray’ cannot be used as a variable at (1)
test1.f90:29:17:
     sd= size(myarray);
             1
Error: ‘array’ argument of ‘size’ intrinsic at (1) must be an array
Compilation failed.
```

I believe the issue is my declaration of structure of the array. I am missing something there.  Any suggestions?  Note that in gfortran code in list1 values I had to change character 'Cc' into 'C' to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike in the Matlab case, where `struct` creates an object with the given values, the `type` statement in Fortran doesn't.

Instead, `type myarray` defines what an object would look like.  No object is created, and we need to do something like

```
type myarray
   ...   ! The definition of components
end type myarray
type(myarray) obj ! Declare an object of the defined type.
```

After this, `obj` is your object of interest.

However, there's more to note.  With

```
type myarray
  character, dimension(8)::list1=(/'A','C','B','E','F','G','H','I'/); 
  integer, dimension(8)::list2 =(/1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8/); 
  integer, dimension(8)::list3 =(/3,3,3,3,3,2,2/);
end type
```

you aren't (again) creating an object.  When you *do* create an object (using `type(myarray) obj`, that object likely starts with those values specified.  This isn't quite the same things as you may expect with the Matlab `struct` statement, though.  You can read about *default initialization* and *constructors* for details of that.

Coming to `size(myarray)`, an object declared solely as `type(myarray) obj` is a *scalar* object.  This is the difference between "arrays of structures" and "structures of arrays".  The "structure" `myarray` contains three arrays each of length 8.  To instead have an array of structures:

```
type myarray
  character list1
  integer list2, list3
end type myarray
type(myarray), dimension(8) :: array
```

You will, however, have to construct the array.  Perhaps

```
array = [myarray('A',1,3), myarray('C',2,3), ...]
```

Other question have answers which go in to details of constructing such arrays of structures.

Comment: the command 'size' has nothing to do with "changing size".  It has to do with determination of array size.  The matlab numel means determine the dimension of the array which is 8.  I think this is equivalent to "size" in gfortran.

Comment: Yes, I didn't write that part correctly.  What I meant to write (and will edit), is that the derived type object you have in the Fortran code is _scalar_.

Comment: your example of array construction solved my problem. Although "Cc" cannot be used , I will see if I can solve that or get away with it. So what is the fortran equivalent for list1.list1 (in octave)?

Comment: If you mean `myarray.list1` then `array%list1`.  You should find such details in any (good) description of using Fortran's derived types.